# How to call shared jsp's using Maven Overlay

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, overlay

I am trying to share a resource of `jsp`'s file of the maven web application using overlay. My project consist of

1. `com.example.common`
2. `com.example.child`

I want to use the `jsp`'s of `com.example.common` in this directory

```
src
|__main
   |__webapp
      |__WEB-INF
         |__view
            |__app
               |__example.jsp
```

so i create dependency refer to `com.example.common` inside `pom.xml` of `com.example.child` like this

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>com.example.common</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

and declare overlay on `pom.xml` of `com.example.child` like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <overlays>
            <overlay>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.example.common</artifactId>
                <type>war</type>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.jsp</include>
                </includes>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF/view</targetPath>
            </overlay>
        </overlays>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

at the end, this is how i call the `jsp` of `com.example.common` from controller of `com.example.child`

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/getparentjsp"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getParentJSP() {
  return "app/example";
}
```

and the output is `HTTP Status 404 - /com.example.child/WEB-INF/view/app/example.jsp`

which it should be goes to `/com.example.common/WEB-INF/view/app/example.jsp`

Are there anything i missed about this `overlay` concepts? Any hint will be very appreciated. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In `child` project add the scope of `common` project as

```
<scope>runtime</scope>
```

If you have to include everything from `common` project, then use the default settings where you do not need to specify `<overlay>` attribute.

If you still want the control over settings, then can you try removing `<targetPath>` attribute.

More details can be found [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) for overlays.

Comment: does it mean we actually can share any resource on `common` just by declaring it on `child` dependencies without specify `<overlay>`?

Comment: @lloistborn, yes you can share the all resources under `webapps` directory like `css`, `js`, etc

Comment: now, the issue is the server always failed to start, it says `FAIL - Deployed application at context path /child but context failed to start` do you know why does this occurs?

Comment: i try removing the overlay dependency and it works again

Comment: Can you share the complete stacktrace?

Comment: well, i think i made mistake somewhere and it works now, but with different error `HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.hasMethodAnnotation(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z`.

Now i have declared `<scope>runtime</scope>` and remove the `<overlay>` on build plugins.

Comment: Looks like you have different versions of `spring`. Can you please check the output of `jar -tvf {YOUR-WAR-NAME}.war`?

Comment: i only have these on `child`-> `spring-webmvc` `spring-context-support` `spring-orm` `spring-tx`. The version is the same as `common`

Comment: Can you share the output of `mvn dependency:tree --projects child`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152069/discussion-between-rishikesh-darandale-and-lloistborn).